# Override JSHint Options by using the Grunt Command-Line

Tags: command-line, parameters, gruntjs, overriding, jshint

By calling

```
grunt jshint:path_to_file
```

I want to override the default JSHint configuration

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
            options: {
              curly: true,
              eqeqeq: true,
              eqnull: true,
              browser: true,
              globals: {
                jQuery: true
              }
            },
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'Scripts/src/**/*.js']
        }

});
```

and only include that specific file.
"grunt jshint path_to_file" would also be okay yet I do not want to use the

```
grunt jshint --file=filePath
```

grunt.option function unless it can do what I need.

Is this achievable somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to use grunt instead of just running `jshint filePath`?

Comment: It's a requirement of our project to only rely on grunt for building, testing etc. to have it all at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spirit of grunt is more to code which files to use in the gruntfile itself than specifying it on the command line.
So we would need more details on why you want to do that. I imagined 2 possibilities:

- you only want to work on a subcomponent: in that case, you would declare different targets for each and call the targets from the command line: `grunt jshint component1` with in your Gruntfile:

  ```
  jshint: {
    component1: [filePath1],
    component2: [filePath2]
  }
  ```
- it's a performance issue: you only want to jshint some files because only them changed. In that case, combine `grunt-contrib-watch` (to run jshint on file change) and `grunt-newer` (to only run on the modified files)

Comment: Thank you for your input so far and I agree that it isn't really in grunts spirit. I read about the grunt watcher but what we need to do is run JSHint on all files which will be checked-in later on which is not possible by a hardcoded grunt subset. Checking in of modified files is only allowed once it passes the JSHint test. If there is really no way to specify it like grunt jshint filepath/subset, I will have to make it work with the watch or newer method you mentioned.

Comment: I think you would be best served by automating everything: run jshint on modified files automatically (using watch + newer) and run jshint on all files as pre-commit hook (if your source control tool allows it). That way, your policy is enforced by your tools.